# How do I use Manipulate with ListLinePlot?

Tags: plotting, manipulate

For example if I have `l = 5 Sqrt[1-β^2]`

This doesn't work `Manipulate[ListLinePlot[{l, l/2}, ScalingFunctions -> {None, {# &, Sqrt[1 - #^2] Sin[Pi/6] &}}], {β, 0, 1}]`

Basically I am trying to show that as beta increases l decreases as represented as the length of a line.

Comment: The main trouble you are seeing is that your dynamic variable, the `β`, doesn't appear *inside* the `Manipulate` function.  Modify it to `l[β_] := 5 Sqrt[1 - β^2];
Manipulate[ListLinePlot[{l[β], l[β]/2},.......`.  Then you need to look at your scaling function to see what good it is doing you, and what it would look like if you took the scaling function out.

Comment: What if β is protected i.e. β >= 0 and β_<=1

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply:

```
Plot[5 Sqrt[1 - β^2], {β,0,1}]
```

Why do you want or need `ListLinePlot`?

And if (for some odd reason) you feel the need for a `Manipulate`:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[5 Sqrt[1 - β^2], {β, 0, 1},
  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[{a, 5 Sqrt[1 - a^2]}]} ],
 {a, 0, 1}]
```